# How to create a new dataframe after the validation_split?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, keras

After training a Keras model and using the `validation_split=0.2` in the `fit()` function, how can we transform that 20% of the old dataframe into a new dataframe for testing?

```
#train model
model.fit(train_X, train_y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=30, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, when you set the `validation_split` argument to `x`, what happens is that the last `x` percent of the training samples is considered as the validation data. Therefore, if you want to get the same validation data used during training you can just slice the dataframe like this:

```
idx = int(len(train_X) * 0.2)  # 0.2 is the value of validation split
# if train_X and train_y are numpy arrays
val_X = train_X[idx:]   
val_y = train_y[idx:]

# if train_X and train_y are pandas dataframes
val_X = train_X.iloc[idx:]
val_y = train_y.iloc[idx:]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what iloc is and give an actual substitution with 0.2 or 20%?

Comment: @Justin It is used for accessing the elements of a pandas dataframe by integer-based location indexing. I have updated my answer to consider numpy arrays as well added validation split value explicitly.